# Using Git in eclipse ( Oxygen 2 version )

Tags: eclipse, github

I use Git in Eclipse version Oxygen 2.I push successfully but no contribution on 
GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

Check your commit information with a simple `git log` from your local repo: the *email* associated to them must be the one you are using in your GitHub account.

See more at the official GitHub page: "[Why are my contributions not showing up on my profile?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/)".

If the email is correct, wait a bit, as the contribution might not be updated immediately.